# Pop up window at a particular time interval

Tags: page-layout

I have a Edit button on my object detail page which is overridden by custom edit page.What I want is on clicking Edit button it should display a pop-up(only between 10 to 11) on which proceed & cancel button will be there.On clicking proceed my custom edit page should be displayed. Cancel will leave the user at same page.All the other times except(10 to 11) clicking on edit button should take the user to custom edit page. I know the condition to check the time. I just want to know how we can override Edit button for this scenario.Any help will be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

You've already overriden the edit button with a VF page.

You can achieve what you want by putting everything in that 1 Visualforce page and rendering only the parts of that page that are relevant at that time.

Create an extra outputpanel on your VF page, containing the proceed and cancel buttons, and render that panel only between those times and if the 'proceed' button has not been clicked (use a boolean set in the APEX controller).

In the outputpanel you can put e.g. an apex:detail page of the object in the background, and on top of that put a popup. There are some guidelines here:
http://www.salesforcegeneral.com/salesforce-modal-dialog-box/

Put the existing part of your VF page in an outputpanel as well (with a rendered= ), and use your APEX controller to determine whether or not to render this panel. So that would be either outside of those hours, or after the proceed button has been clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply. I added the below code to my controller class.

```
public boolean displayPopup { get; set;}     
public void closePopup() {        
    displayPopup = false;    
}     
public void showPopup() { 
Integer currentHourValue = Integer.valueOf(System.Now().format('HH','PST')); 
if(currentHourValue>= 10 && currentHourValue<=11)    
    displayPopup = true;    
}
```

But i m not sure how to create output panel in my custom edit page. You said in that panel i have to create 2 buttons. On cancel i can call closepopup method. But on proceed what action should i provide. And since i will write my out panel panel in my edit page only, how i can render this panel. Please guide.

Comment: In order to keep the overview, please make this an edit to your post and remove this answer. Also that will make sure I receive an update when you do that (I didn't get an update on you adding this answer, looking at it by coincidence)